# Fixing fill on arrows in "compass"

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

How do I fix the coloring in the arrow head? It doesn't fill like the line width does. Also, you'll notice that the arrow touches `D`. How do I push D down? (Or is it best to just manually adjust it?)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, trees, mindmap, calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node (a) at (9,7.5) {};
\node (b) at (9,4.5) {B};
\node (c) at (10.5,6) {};
\node (d) at (7.5,6) {D};

\path[draw=black!60,solid,line width=0.8mm,fill=black!60,preaction={-triangle 90,thin,draw,shorten >=-1mm}] (a) -- (b);
\path[draw=black!60,solid,line width=0.8mm,fill=black!60,preaction={-triangle 90,thin,draw,shorten >=-1mm}] (c) -- (d);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace the `draw` in the `preaction` option with the same style as used for the lines (`fill=black!60`) you get gray-ish arrows (the `draw` from the main action is inherited anyway).

You also shorten the arrow part (so that it will be extend further than the actual line). I’d revert this (as it is done by PGF usually when you place arrows on *one* path), i.e. the actual line is shortened, the arrow is not.

I also have defined a style `thicker line small arrows` that takes its argument in the form `<line width> in <color>`, which can be repeatedly used to style various lines in the same manner.

I also provide another way (the `thicker line small arrows m` style) that uses the `markings` library to place the arrow. This is not as stable as the usual `preaction`/`postaction` method, but you can place the arrow anyway on the path by the `1` in  `at position 1`.

### Code 1

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\colorlet{mygray}{black!60}
\tikzset{thicker line small arrows/.style args={#1in#2}{
    draw=#2,
    solid,
    line width=#1,
    shorten >=1mm,
    preaction={
        fill=#2,
        thin,
        -triangle 90,
        shorten >=0mm,
    }
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node (a) at (9,7.5) {};
\node (b) at (9,4.5) {B};
\node (c) at (10.5,6) {};
\node (d) at (7.5,6) {D};

\path[thicker line small arrows=.8mm in mygray] (a) -- (b);
\path[thicker line small arrows=.4mm in green] (c) -- (d);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Code 2

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.markings}
\colorlet{mygray}{black!60}
\tikzset{thicker line small arrows m/.style args={#1in#2}{
    draw=#2,
    solid,
    line width=#1,
    shorten >=1mm,
    decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 1.0 with {\arrow[fill=#2,thin]{triangle 90}}
    },
    postaction={decorate}
}}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node (a) at (9,7.5) {};
\node (b) at (9,4.5) {B};
\node (c) at (10.5,6) {};
\node (d) at (7.5,6) {D};

\path[thicker line small arrows m=.8mm in mygray] (a) -- (b);
\path[thicker line small arrows m=.4mm in green] (c) -- (d);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]